# Zend Framework 2 - Add style to controller

Tags: css, zend-framework2

I have been looking through the documentation, and I can't seem to find a way to do this. I know I can use headScript to add style sheets to individual views, but I would like to add a style sheet to all actions in a controller.

Has anyone done this? I am sure it is a simple task.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is hook into the `dispatch` event and, based on the type of controller that was dispatched, set the appropriate layout (recommended). You could also directly modify the view and add the required assets.

This can be achieved by using the following code in your `Module` class:

```php
<?php
namespace App;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function (MvcEvent $event)
        {
            $application = $event->getApplication();
            $services = $application->getServiceManager();
            $view = $services->get('ViewRenderer');
            $controller = $event->getTarget();
            if ($controller instanceof \App\Controller\Entry)
            {
                $controller->layout('layout/app/entry');
                // -- OR --
                $view->headStyle()->appendStyle('body{background:red}');
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: So, this would apply an entire layout to the controller (and thus all of its actions)? It could work, but this seems a little overkill just to add a single stylesheet to all actions of a given controller. It's hard for me to believe that they would have taken away this functionality for version 2 (it was pretty simple in version 1)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how you can directly modify the assets without having to duplicate the whole layout.

Comment: Very nice... simpler than I was thinking. Thank you for the update.